# Possible to "drill down" to a SSRS report using Performancepoint analytics charts?

Tags: performancepoint, business-intelligence

I would like to open either a reporting services report or a SharePoint list when clicking a pie chart in a Performancepoint dashboard. This would replace the "standard" functionality of  drilling down further and displaying a new piechart.

If a list is opened then the value selected in the chart needs to be set as a filter in the opened list.

In my head I have the option of using javascript to do this but it does not seem very efficient when I need to create around 60 different dashboards.

The elements in the dashboard are connected to cubes in SSAS whereas the reports/list needs to display items stored in the data warehouse (Either in a view or a table).

What should I be googling?

Comment: Did you find any solution on this? I'm trying to do the same thing, but haven't found any solution. Best regards,
Shakir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing was use SSRS reports with go to url actions containing some javascript instead of trying to build something on top of PerformancePoint.

One report with pie (connected to the cube) passing params to a report (connected to the data warehouse).